# with react , display a menu if the mouse is on an image

Tags: reactjs, image, menu

I want to display a menu if the cursor is on an image, and the the menu is leaving if the cursor is not on the menu or the image

heres what i tried to do but it doesnt work, in menu theres my menu list
i also tried to put everything in the same component but its not working

```
import "../styles/Background.css";
import Menu from './Menu'
import { useState } from "react";
import skull from '../assets/bg3.gif'

  
  function Background () {
    const title = "Blog"
    const title_header = "True Crime Story"
    const[showMenu,setShowMenu] = useState(false)
   

  return (
    <div className="body">
        <div className="modal">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <title>{title}</title>
                <div className="main-title">
                    <h1>{title_header}</h1>
                </div>
                <p>Latin text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src={skull} className="image" onMouseOver={()=>setShowMenu(true)}/>
        {showMenu ? <Menu/> : null}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Background
```

Comment: `onMouseOver={()=>setShowMenu(true)}`

Comment: tried and its not working :/

Answer (score 1):

Depending your use case, you can handle this either with pure CSS or with state.

With CSS (give a `className` to the menu `<div>`):

```
/* when .image is hovered inside .body, set display to .menu */

body:has(.image:hover) .menu {
  display: block;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

With state:

```
function Background() {
  const title = "Blog"
  const title_header = "True Crime Story"
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false)

  const handleMouseOver = () => {
    setShowMenu(true)
  }

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setShowMenu(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className="body">
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <title>{title}</title>
          <div className="main-title">
            <h1>{title_header}</h1>
          </div>
          <p>Latin text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={scull} className="image" onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} />
      {showMenu ? <div className="menu">ezbdb</div> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer will work.

Additionally, adding mouse events directly to the HTML `<img>` tag is possible but generally not recommended. It's better to add mouse events to a parent element that wraps the image, such as a `<div>` or `<a>` tag, for proper event handling and image-related actions.

Hope it help :)